# Finding exposure duration of a webcam in time units?

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, hdr

I'm experimenting with HDR capture at the moment and using a Logitech C920 through OpenCV via python. All the camera calibration algorithms I have come across to date require the actual duration of the image exposure or at least known ratios between the various exposure times. Unfortunately all I have when setting the exposure time in OpenCV (CAM_PROP_EXPOSURE) for the C920 is an integer range [-11 to -2] with no indication of units.

Is there a low level API or utility that I can probe the camera with to find the corresponding duration in seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it - turns out OpenCV is going through DirectShow in the back end for the camera and according to the appropriate documentation [ICameraControl::get_Exposure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376313(v=vs.85).aspx) the mystery values are encoding the exposure duration:

> pValue
>
> Receives the exposure time, in log base 2 seconds. If the value is n, the exposure time is 2^n seconds.

while the log of a negative number makes no sense and I guess must be an error, the second part about 2^n seconds seems credible. This would give -2 as 1/4 of a second and -11 as 1/2048 of a second with the exposure times doubling/halving each integer step.

Comment: Well done - thanks for sharing back with the community.